# Android app can be launched when press icon?

Tags: java, android

I've build my project as .apk file and then I installed it into my device. 
My step is:

1) Press an icon in app drawer, the Main Activity was started.

2) Press some action to go to Second Activity

3) Press Home Button

4) Press icon again

My expectation is the Second Activity should be resume but it just relaunch Main Activity.

How can I fix that I have tried set LaunchMode as

android:launchMode="singleTask"

android:launchMode="singleTop"

but it doesn't work.

Here is my setting in Manifest.xml file

```
            <activity
        android:name=".auction.MySplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking form your manifest file,Your problem is due to android:launchMode property set by you.You should set it as default or you can also avoid to set it.Using this way your desired behavior can be obtained.

Answer (score 1):

In manifest file if you have declared any activity with intent filter having action main and category launcher then that is known to be your first activity or main activity to start your application.

Now in any android smart phone application starts from two way.

1) Home screen/Launcher screen 
Behavior : Now if you press any icon over here then the launcher would see the manifest file of the application and look for the activity having the intent action launcher and main then it will call that activity.

2) Recent Apps/Long press home button
Behavior : Any recent app that you have opened will be shown here and the Android will have the all the track record of the app and when you press any icon the app will be shown with the latest activity you browsed

---

So the behavior you are having is the default behavior and there is not any error/glitch in that. That's the way it should be.

---

Solution to your problem :

If you want to show your splash screen only once in application life time then you need to have some Boolean and store it in sharedprefrences and use it to check weather you are first time or not..if its not first time then directly call the next activity using intent.

Comment: You suggestion is make-sense but I still don't understand one more thing. If I run the application with debugger this case doesn't happen I really don't understand why?